# TextField from Material-UI goes into Header area

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

When scrolling the page, the `TextField` on the page is visible on `header` area. The `header` is created with css and I am using `TextField` from `material-ui`.

I have never created an header with css before. Is there maybe some code that has to be included, when creating an header? see code below.

- Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

```
.toolbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #02ABED;
    height: 56px;
}

.toolbar__navigation {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 1rem;
}

.toolbar__logo a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.spacer {
    flex: 1;
}

.toolbar_navigation-items ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.toolbar_navigation-items li {
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.toolbar_navigation-items a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.toolbar_navigation-items a:hover,
.toolbar_navigation-items a:active {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a working example (you can use https://codesandbox.io for that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem, I fixed this by setting the `z-index`, see code below:

```
.toolbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #02ABED;
    height: 56px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```